# Python - Identify non ascii characters in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

**Goal**: Need a process for identifying non-ascii characters in various csv files

I have csv files with non-ascii characters in some of the data (e.g. one or two employee ids out of thousands will have a random non-ascii character). I want to identify these for cleanup, but I'm getting a unicode error when I try to read in the csv which I believe is due to the same non-ascii characters. The emp_id column is normally a number and I'm converting it to a string in this example because the function I'm using won't work with integers. I need to be able to apply this code to strings and integers.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
isascii = lambda s: len(s) ==len(s.encode())

df = pd.read_csv("C:\\python_files\\data.csv", dtype={'EMP_ID': object})

for x in df['EMP_ID']:
    if not isascii(x):
        print(x)
```

**Error**

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 3: invalid start byte
```

**Sample Data**
EMP_ID
34998
34994
A2…
04™Œ
00`,
99999

Answer (score 0):

You should add `encoding` to your `read_csv` code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\python_files\\data.csv", dtype={'EMP_ID': object}, encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: I tried that but I still get the same Unicode error.

Comment: sample data added

Comment: Your code actually worked for me on that sample of data, what version of Python/Pandas you use?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.1. I believe the problem characters aren't pasting into

Comment: I mean that the problem characters aren't pasting into my question here.